setting an environment variable from another pipeline
from pipeline A im triggering pipeline B.
In pipeline A, I have an environment variable thats empty which I want to set a value, using pipeline B.
how can I acheive this?

If I understand correctly, there is no way.
Because the life cycle of pipeline A has already ended, when it called pipeline b.
Perhaps the ideal is to change your approach to interacting with Jobs, rather than the environment.

You can use the build step to trigger the pipeline B and then examine its return value. Mind you, it's the step return value, not the pipeline return value. Unfortunately pipelines are not designed to return any values besides result (status, like SUCCESS or FAILURE). But you can repurpose some of the rarely used properties, description is a common choice.
Pipeline A:
def childPipeline = build 'pipelineB'
env.MY_VAR = childPipeline.description // "foo"
echo env.MY_VAR

Pipeline B:
currentBuild.description = "foo"

